# How to detect contact format from Android device

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am building an Android application where I need to detect the contact format (fields like firstname, lastname, nickname, phone, email, IM  etc) from the user's Android handset. How can I do it?

I googled for it since from last 5 days but I didn't get any reply...please suggest me.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html - examples included

Comment: What does the term "contact format" mean?

Comment: In short in my application I want to retrieve number of field of contacts(i.e. name, phone, IM, email, nickname etc) supported by particular device.
how can I do it??